# I have tried to plot in matlab but matlab plot is not working

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

I have tried to plot a code in Matlab. But it is not working. Just figure window has come out but no figure is shown on that window. What can I do now? 
I have tried this code from a youtube playlist called [Control Bootcamp](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qjhAAQexzLg&list=PLMrJAkhIeNNR20Mz-VpzgfQs5zrYi085m&index=12&pbjreload=10) and my Matlab version is **R2018a**.

This is the main code:

```
clear all, close all, clc

m = 1;
M = 5;
L = 2;
g = -10;
d = 1;

tspan = 0:.1:4;
y0 = [0; 0; pi; .5];
[t,y] = ode45(@(t,y)cartpend(y,m,M,L,g,d,0),tspan,y0); %cartpend is a function

for k=1:length(t)
    drawcartpend_bw(y(k,:),m,M,L);
end
```

I have tried to plot the trajectory of a inverted Pendulum. So I have declared function a function called `cartpend`. `drawcartpend_bw` is used to draw the trajectory of the `cartpend`.

```
function dy = cartpend(y,m,M,L,g,d,u)

Sy = sin(y(3));
Cy = cos(y(3));
D = m*L*L*(M+m*(1-Cy^2));

dy(1,1) = y(2);
dy(2,1) = (1/D)*(-m^2*L^2*g*Cy*Sy + m*L^2*(m*L*y(4)^2*Sy - d*y(2))) + m*L*L*(1/D)*u;
dy(3,1) = y(4);
dy(4,1) = (1/D)*((m+M)*m*g*L*Sy - m*L*Cy*(m*L*y(4)^2*Sy - d*y(2))) - m*L*Cy*(1/D)*u +.01*randn;
```

This is the `cartpend` function. I have declared the equation of inverted pendulum in here.

```
function drawcartpend_bw(y,m,M,L)
x = y(1);
th = y(3);

% kinematics
% x = 3;        % cart position
% th = 3*pi/2;   % pendulum angle

% dimensions
% L = 2;  % pendulum length
W = 1*sqrt(M/5);  % cart width
H = .5*sqrt(M/5); % cart height
wr = .2; % wheel radius
mr = .3*sqrt(m); % mass radius

% positions
% y = wr/2; % cart vertical position
y = wr/2+H/2; % cart vertical position
w1x = x-.9*W/2;
w1y = 0;
w2x = x+.9*W/2-wr;
w2y = 0;

px = x + L*sin(th);
py = y - L*cos(th);

plot([-10 10],[0 0],'w','LineWidth',2)
hold on
rectangle('Position',[x-W/2,y-H/2,W,H],'Curvature',.1,'FaceColor',[1 0.1 0.1],'EdgeColor',[1 1 1])
rectangle('Position',[w1x,w1y,wr,wr],'Curvature',1,'FaceColor',[1 1 1],'EdgeColor',[1 1 1])
rectangle('Position',[w2x,w2y,wr,wr],'Curvature',1,'FaceColor',[1 1 1],'EdgeColor',[1 1 1])

plot([x px],[y py],'w','LineWidth',2)

rectangle('Position',[px-mr/2,py-mr/2,mr,mr],'Curvature',1,'FaceColor',[.3 0.3 1],'EdgeColor',[1 1 1])

% set(gca,'YTick',[])
% set(gca,'XTick',[])
xlim([-5 5]);
ylim([-2 2.5]);
set(gca,'Color','k','XColor','w','YColor','w')
set(gcf,'Position',[10 900 800 400])
set(gcf,'Color','k')
set(gcf,'InvertHardcopy','off')   

% box off
drawnow
hold off
```

Here, I tried to draw the function. But drawing is not working. I don't know why.

Comment: Remove all the `xlim`, `ylim` and `set` calls, which modify the graph. You should see your figure then. Add those calls back in one by one, to see which one causes the problems.

Comment: The issue is simple. Just remove the following line because it makes the figure display out of your screen dimensions, therefore, you can't see the output. `set(gcf,'Position',[10 900 800 400])`

Comment: If @Mohammadnagdawi is right, you should see another window opens for the figure in the taskbar, but selecting it or hovering it won't show anything

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a compatibility issue between matlab versions, because I tried this code in Matlab **R2016a** and it's working. Also, the guy from youtube is using Matlab 2015. What you can do if you are not receiving any error/ warning messages, is to google the changes from Matlab 2015 to 2018 [1](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html?rntext=&startrelease=R2015b&endrelease=R2018a&groupby=release&sortby=descending&searchHighlight=), and try to see if something from what you are using in your code has been changed.